# PIP build does not include other dll's

Tags: ocean, petrel

WHen doing a PIP build it will copy in the solutions other projects outputs from the DeployList.xml but for a different project outside of this solution I only copied in the dll.  However it does not like this and throws an error:

Ignored C:\Test.dll because it cannot be loaded properly due to:
    An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B) Source: Slb.Ocean.Core

I have also included other files and it copies them in just fine.  It just seems to have an issue with dll's and exe's.

Answer (score 1):

If the .dll you are trying to add is a native DLL (without a managed header), the PluginPackager displays the warning message you have given, like this one when trying to add Inventor.dll:

*Ignored D:\Program Files\Schlumberger\Petrel 2012\Extensions\OceanLab\Inventor.dll because it cannot be loaded properly due to:
   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   Source: Slb.Ocean.Core*

[though you would never need to include any .dlls that are part of Petrel, this is just an example]

However, these messages do not keep the .PIP from building, nor do they keep the referenced native .dlls from being included in the generated .PIP file.

There is a enhancement requirement recorded to clean up these misleading messages.